# hobby: trouble getting tangency information at a point to affect drawn path as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, hobby

Consider the minimum not working example here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, hobby}
\tikzset{
        tangent/.style = {
            in angle={(180+#1)},
            Hobby finish,
            designated Hobby path=next,
            out angle=#1
        }
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}

        \coordinate (y) at (0,3);
        \coordinate (x) at (5,0);

        \coordinate (sp0) at (1.5,0);
        \coordinate (ep0) at (3.5,2);
        \coordinate (csp0) at (2.5,1);
        \coordinate (cep0) at (2.75,0);

        \coordinate (sp1) at (ep0);
        \coordinate (ep1) at (4.5,3);
        \coordinate (csp1) at (4.25,4);
        \coordinate (cep1) at (4.25,2);

        \coordinate (sp2) at (sp0);
        \coordinate (ep2) at (0,-1);
        \coordinate (csp2) at (0.5,-1);
        \coordinate (cep2) at (0.5,-1);

        \draw[<->] (y) node[left] {$f(x)$} -- (0,0) --  (x) node[below] {$x$};

        % Using \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints to calculate the angle for tangent
        % tangent takes a degree unit angle
        \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{cep0}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{ep0}{center}}
        \let\angle=\pgfmathresult
        \draw (ep2) to [curve through ={(sp0) .. ([tangent=\angle]ep0)}] (ep1) ;

        \draw[dashed] (cep0) -- (csp1);
        \draw[dotted] let \p1 = (ep0) in (ep0) -- (0,\y1);
        \draw[dotted] let \p1 = (ep0) in (ep0)-- (\x1,0);

        \draw let \p1 = (ep0) in (\x1,1pt) -- (\x1,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_0$};
        \draw let \p1 = (cep0) in (\x1,1pt) -- (\x1,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_1$};
        \draw let \p1 = (ep0) in (1pt,\y1) -- (-3pt,\y1) node [anchor=east] {$f(x_0)$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Newton's method in action: diagram drawn using the \texttt{hobby} package.}
        \label{fig:newton_method_2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It produces output like so:

[image: Newton redux]

However, if the angle information was working as I would have expected it to, then the solid path drawn by `hobby` would have been tangent to the sloped dashed line. I have tried tweaking a few things, and my impression is that the "angle" information affects the path relative to the direction of path rather than some standard coordinate system (I would have expected 0 degrees to be in the direction of the positive x-axis, and positive angles representing CCW deviations from the positive x-axis)?

How can I get it to work as I expect? Or alternatively, how does the tangent function as defined work compared to how I expect it to?

Comment: [Like this and in many of your other questions ;).] Not entirely minimal, but pretty close!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tangent` option wasn't designed to be used with the `curve through` syntax since it was written to fix a problem that the `curve through` syntax doesn't have.  The `tangent` option works with the shortcut syntax.  The problem is that if one wants to follow a Hobby curve by another Hobby curve then this is difficult to signal using the shortcut syntax but not with the `curve through` variant.  The `tangent` key is designed to make it easy to insert such a break.

So your code works with the shortcut code:

```
\draw[use Hobby shortcut] (ep2)  .. (sp0) .. ([tangent=\angle]ep0) .. (ep1) ;
```

It also works with the `curve through` if I manually put the break in:

```
\draw (ep2) to [curve through ={([out angle=\angle]sp0)}] (ep0);
```

except that the second part of the curve (from `(ep0)` to `(ep1)`) doesn't have a middle point and the `curve through` doesn't really cope well with that.

So I think I recommend the shortcut syntax for what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and especially for making this package!